# Backbone Facade/Mediator Pattern Challenge

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, requirejs, facade

I'm toying around with the aura(http://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-aura) example implementing *Facade* and *Mediator* patterns in Backbone.js. I hope someone is familiar with the concept.. I'm trying to read variables (for instance **i** in this example in the *renderComplete* section of the facade.
how can i (if even possible) access the functions/variables of Appview?

The console.log(this.i); returns an undefined so i'm guessing i've lost scope somewhere

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/master.html',
  '../aura/mediator',
  '../aura/facade',
  '../subscriptions'
], function($, _, Backbone, masterTemplate, Mediator, Facade){

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "body",
  i : 5,

  template: _.template(masterTemplate),

  facade: {
    routeChange: Facade.extend("masterViewChange", "routeChanged", function(route){
      console.log("Change view to " + this.i);
    }),
    renderComplete: Facade.extend("postMasterRender", "masterRendered", function(){
      console.log(this.i);  
    })
  },

  events: {},

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    Mediator.publish("masterRendered", this);
  },

  render: function() {
   $(this.el).html(this.template());
  }

});
  return AppView;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish the 'masterRendered' notification, your are passing a reference to the current view as a second param (this). This second param is passed to the callback function you defined in renderComplete. So you need to write something like this:

```
function (obj) { console.log(obj.i); }
```

Instead of:

```
function () { console.log(this.i); }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your facade methods to your View context by doing something like this in the initializer for the View:

```
initialize: function()
{
    _.bindAll(this, "facade.routeChange", "facade.renderComplete");
}
```

Though I question whether _.bindAll can handle this case where the function you want to bind is a property of another object.